# gulp-livereload reloading before server process finishes restarting

Tags: javascript, gulp, livereload, nodemon

I'm configuring my [gulp.js](http://gulpjs.com/) gulpfile to watch my directory for file changes, and 1) reload my express server and 2) issue a livereload "change" event so that my browser (with the LiveReload chrome extension) will reload the page that I'm developing.

Here's my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
  , nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon')
  , livereload = require('gulp-livereload');

gulp.task('startReloadServer', function() {
  livereload.listen();
});

gulp.task('demon', function () {
  nodemon({
    script: 'server.js',
    ext: 'js html',
    env: {
      'NODE_ENV': 'development'
    }
  })
    .on('start', ['startReloadServer'])
    .on('restart', function () {
      console.log('restarted!');
      livereload.changed();
    });
});

gulp.task('default', ['demon']);
```

Yet when I make a change to one of my view (.html) files, my browser reloads the page before the node server process has had an opportunity to come back online:

[image: failed browser request]

How do I alter my gulpfile to have the livereload.changed() event be issued *after* nodemon is ready to receive requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found similar question, then I write my solution.
[Gulp to watch when node app.listen() is invoked or to port (livereload, nodejs and gulp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217978/gulp-to-watch-when-node-app-listen-is-invoked-or-to-port-livereload-nodejs-a/29531483#29531483)

```
nodemon({script: 'app.js',
         nodeArgs: ['--harmony'],
         stdout: false})
    .on('readable', function(data) {
        this.stdout.on('data', function(chunk) {
            if (/koa server listening/.test(chunk)) {
                console.log('livereload');
                livereload.reload();
            }
            process.stdout.write(chunk);
        });
        this.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this problem. This best I could come up with was to delay the call to `livereload.changed()` for one second.

```js
nodemon.on('restart', function() {
  setTimeout(livereload.changed, 1000);
});
```

docs: [setTimeout](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_arg)