# Gulp to watch when node app.listen() is invoked or to port (livereload, nodejs and gulp)

Tags: node.js, gulp, livereload, gulp-livereload

I am trying to get `gulp-livereload` to work with my nodejs server. I am using `gulp-nodemon` to restart the server after changes to the files, this works. I am having trouble invoking `livereload.reload()` at the correct time.

I am currently invoking `livereload.reload()` on the `.on('start'...` in my `gulpfile.js` (whenever my nodemon starts a script). This works but it takes a few seconds. The reason is when nodemon starts to run the nodejs script it invokes `livereload.listen()` *before* the script has invoked `app.listen(port)`, so my browser refreshs without the server being ready.

Is there a way to listen if the nodejs nodemon script has invoked `app.listen(port)` or perhaps listen to see if a specific port is being used?

I have fixed the issue with a small sleep but it just feels so wrong and dirty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use readable event to monitor stdout of child process.

example:

```
nodemon({script: 'app.js',
         nodeArgs: ['--harmony'],
         stdout: false})
    .on('readable', function(data) {
        this.stdout.on('data', function(chunk) {
            if (/koa server listening/.test(chunk)) {
                console.log('livereload');
                livereload.reload();
            }
            process.stdout.write(chunk);
        });
        this.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
    });
```

app.js

```
app.listen(3000, function(err) {
    console.log('koa server listening');
});
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a an example of [simple and **tested** livereload solution](https://github.com/dmitriz/gulp-automation) based on `connect` server and `connect-livereload` and `gulp-livereload` plugins if that is of any help:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var connect = require('connect');
var connectLivereload = require('connect-livereload');
var opn = require('opn');
var gulpLivereload = require('gulp-livereload');

var config = {
    rootDir: __dirname,
    servingPort: 8080,

    // the files you want to watch for changes for live reload
    filesToWatch: ['*.{html,css,js}', '!Gulpfile.js']
}

// The default task - called when you run `gulp` from CLI
gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'serve']);

gulp.task('watch', ['connect'], function () {
  gulpLivereload.listen();
  gulp.watch(config.filesToWatch, function(file) {
    gulp.src(file.path)
      .pipe(gulpLivereload());
  });
});

gulp.task('serve', ['connect'], function () {
  return opn('http://localhost:' + config.servingPort);
});

gulp.task('connect', function(){
  return connect()
    .use(connectLivereload())
    .use(connect.static(config.rootDir))
    .listen(config.servingPort);
});
```